# Typescript: create generic Unwrap<T> helper type

Tags: typescript

I've created a helper type to unwrap the inner type of an `Observable<T>`:

```
type UnwrapObservable<T> = T extends Observable<(infer U)> ? U : never;
```

This works just fine.  But... my next thought was, "How can I make this type completely generic and apply to any type, not just Observable, essentially `Unwrap<T>`?

Here's what I tried:

```
type Unwrap<T, W> = T extends W<(infer U)> ? U : never;
```

But I get:

> Type 'W' is not generic. ts(2315)

How can I create a type that unwraps any specified type?

Comment: I guess, you want to express [higher-kinded types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), where `W` is a type constructor applied on a specific type, like `W<*>`. You can give the issue an upvote to encourage its development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What You are trying to do is impossible in TS, but as far as I know it is possible in Flow)

In TS you can't apply restrictions for generic which expects other generic as argument.

This is the most generic `Wrap` type

```js
type Wrapp<T> = { wrapped: T }
type Unwrap<T> = T extends Wrapp<(infer R)> ? R : never
```

Please see [here](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types/issues/18) for similar limitation